# A nonlinear or quadratic programming solver for Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, optimization, solver

Does anyone knows a nonlinear or quadratic programming solver for Ruby? or a way to connect ruby to a nonlinear solver?

I appreciate any help,

Regards.

Comment: What sort of problem are you trying to solve?  There is a GSL gem, and although I do not believe GSL has a QP solver, it does have a nonlinear solver.

Comment: I think GSL is not useful to my problem, beacause I need to add linear constrain.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ruby/GSL gem (rb-gsl)](http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/) has a [non-linear solver](http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/files/rdoc/nonlinearfit_rdoc.html).

Try installing that gem and following the code examples from its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several good [nonlinear programming solvers in Python](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/83/is-there-a-high-quality-nonlinear-programming-solver-for-python). Try calling a Python function from Ruby.

```rb
result = `python script.py`
```

Here is an example nonlinear programming problem.

[image: nonlinear programming]

Solve it with Ruby by saving Python code as `script.py`

```py
from gekko import GEKKO    
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Array(m.Var,4,value=1,lb=1,ub=5)
x1,x2,x3,x4 = x
# change initial values
x2.value = 5; x3.value = 5
m.Equation(x1*x2*x3*x4>=25)
m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2+x4**2==40)
m.Minimize(x1*x4*(x1+x2+x3)+x3)
m.solve()
print('x: ', x)
print('Objective: ',m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
```

Gekko solves linear, nonlinear, mixed integer, equality, inequality, and differential algebraic equations.